# Formatting the data

Tags: mysql, octave

I have data in this format. Values are on the yearly basis.

countryname 1990 1991 1992 are the names of column.

Nepal        5    10   15; India        20   25    30 are the rows.

I want to convert this data into the format using MYSQL query or just octave as below -

countryname year value has to be the columns. 
Rows should be like this : Nepal       1990 5;Nepal       1991 10;Nepal       1992  15;India       1990  5;

Comment: In my opinion, I think you need to restructure your table. Have it properly normalized. Thanks.

Comment: Column names can't be numbers... are you saying you already have a mysql table like this? If so, what are the actual column names?

Comment: Dear Dan, column names are not the numbers. They are numeral strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your column names are actually `1990y`, `1991y` etc (since you can't use a plain number as column name) then you can get the table you want using SQL like this:

```
SELECT countryname, 1990, 1990y FROM yourTable
UNION
SELECT countryname, 1991, 1991y FROM yourTable
UNION
SELECT countryname, 1992, 1992y FROM yourTable
```

In Octave you can do:

```
n = size(data, 1);
norm_data = [];
for y = 1990:1992
    N(:,1) = data(:,1);
    N(:,2) = y;
    N(:,3) = data(:,y-1990+2);
    norm_data(end:end+n,:) = N;
end
```

Comment: Thank you Dan for your answer. I will try this.

Comment: Thank you so much Dan. I changed the column names and it really worked for me.